# Travelling to Ireland with UK short-term student visa with no BIVS endorsement (Indian passport)

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, ireland

I am an Indian passport holder. I am currently on university exchange in the UK using my UK Type C Short-term Student Visa (i.e. NOT a Tier 4 long-term student visa). My UK visa is valid for 180 days. This visa was issued in India.

I would like to visit Dublin, ROI for a few days during my university break. While it appears that I meet the criteria for the Irish short stay visa waiver programme, my visa does not mention anything about a "BIVS endorsement".

1. Can I still travel to Ireland for a few days regardless, considering that I meet all other criteria?
2. If not, then is there a way for me to apply for a BIVS endorsement on my pre-existing UK visa without having to apply for a separate Irish visa altogether? (Assuming that would be the faster route.)
3. If not, then how do I apply for and be issued an Irish visa soon? The Irish visa website mentions that it may take up to 8 weeks; however, I would want to travel to Ireland in March (it is February now)  and also travel to other countries in the meanwhile.

Comment: Were you able to travel with UK short term student visa?

Answer (score 4):

You have a Short Term Study visa, [which is not eligible for the scheme](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/british-irish-visa-scheme/british-irish-visa-scheme).

> Indian and Chinese nationals can travel to Ireland and the UK using the following UK visas:
>
> - all standard visitor categories where the maximum period for a single visit is six months
> - Permitted Paid Engagement visas

The Short Term Study Visa is not a category of Standard Visitor Visa.

You must apply for an Irish visa to travel to Ireland, there is no other option.

Comment: But according to an FAQ sheet put out by the Irish consulate in India, [some student visas are also eligible for the scheme](https://www.dfa.ie/media/embassyindia/BIVS-FAQ---PDF-version-Jan-2017.pdf):

"Student Visitor visa – Only for 6 months or less." (page 4)

In this case, please let me know if I can still travel to Ireland? Or if there is any way to get a BIVS endorsement on my pre-existing UK visa without getting a new Irish visa entirely?

Comment: @HollyMolly That information is out of date. The Student Visitor Visa no longer exists. All of the "visit" visas were rolled into the Standard Visitor Visa. If your visa were eligible, it would have endorsement. Since it doesn't, it is not eligible, and there is no way to obtain it. Sorry.